# Can I take classroom supplies provided by a grant after a year of use

Tags: funding

I wrote a grant for 10 whiteboards for my classroom last year.  The grant was not a group grant, but an individual project grant. I used them for this year and am looking to move schools.

Would I be entitled to take these whiteboards with me, or are they attached to the school? I cannot find the specifics in the grant stating this, other than it was required to be used for this school year.

Comment: By "school" do you mean a college or university, or a primary/secondary school (e.g. K-12)?  The topic of this site is only the former.

Answer (score 5):

This would depend on the details of the grant. It is likely, however, that the grant was to the institution, not to you as an individual. I'm surprised it isn't clear in the grant. Perhaps it can be made clear if you ask the funding agency.

You might also need to negotiate it with your institution so you don't get accused of theft by taking them.

I've had grants that specified myself as the recipient, though they were from companies. And, even then, the institution managed the funds to assure they were used properly.

Answer (score 1):

It usually depends on the school policy, not the grant policy. Usually things bought with grants transfer to the school, then the school disposes as per their own policy. In my experience, there's no way to predict, and you have to ask. Don't take without asking, though. If there is a policy against it, it's grounds for firing.

Comment: "Grounds for firing" is not particularly important if the scenario is wanting to take equipment with you when you move to another job, which is the case for the OP. Theft, however, is also illegal.

Comment: The OP is "looking to move schools", so I think it's fair to assume he/she does not want to get fired before they have secured the next job.   Most schools have a strict decommissioning protocol, that's why it's important to ask first.

Comment: I don't see how they would be taking classroom supplies with them before they have secured the next job.